# pthread_mutex_timedlock on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, pthreads

I am porting window mutexes to linux using pthreads and compiling with gcc. I came across `WaitForSingleObject` function on windows. I am trying to use `pthread_mutex_timedlock` to lock the mutex for an x amount of seconds just like `WaitForSingleObject`.

I included the `time.h` and `pthread.h` files but when I try to compile, I get an undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_timedlock` error. When I take an argument out of `pthread_mutex_timedlock` and try to compile, I get

> too few arguments to function "pthread_mutex_timedlock"

I am confused as to why I am getting the undefined reference error. A snippet of my code is below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int dwWaitResult;
struct timespec timeout;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
timeout.tv_sec = 10;

dwWaitResult = pthread_mutex_timedlock(mutexArray[mutexIndex], &timeout);
```

Comment: undefined reference means that yo udo not link agains pthread lib; did you try adding -lpthread?

Comment: FYI, there are a lot of libs doing this kind of wrapping, did you try to have a look to them?

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried adding -pthread (im using gcc 4.8.5), I still get the same errors.

Comment: could you provide the full error( in your question)?

Comment: Nevermind! It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined reference means that yo udo not link agains pthread lib; did you try adding -lpthread? @OznOg

OznOg answered my question. I just needed to use -pthread when compiling. Thank you!!

Comment: **N.B.**  `-pthread` is subtly different than `-lpthread`. One should use `-pthread` which (from gcc man page) "Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker."